# PFImageView not showing up in the window

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode6

I'm trying my hand at parse with a snapchat clon and everything is going fine, but when I have to display the images for the user the PFImageView is not showing up, I have no idea as no errors show up just no subview.

The offending part:

```
func checkForMessages() {

if PFUser.currentUser()?.username != nil {

    println("checking for msgs")

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Image")
    query.whereKey("recipientUsername", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

    var msgs = query.findObjects()

    println("\(msgs?.count) \(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!) recipientUsername")

    var done  = false

    if let msg = msgs as? [PFObject] {
        for msgReceived in msg {

            if done == false {

                var imageView: PFImageView = PFImageView()

                imageView.file = msgReceived["image"] as? PFFile

                imageView.loadInBackground({

                    (photo, error) -> Void in


                    if error == nil {

                        var displayedImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height))

                        displayedImage.image = photo

                        println(photo!.description)

                        self.view.addSubview(imageView) //here it should place it in the view
                    }
                })


                done = true
            }

        }

    }

    println(msgs?.count)
} else {

    println("waiting for user this should be not showing")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Supporting Files/ParseStarterProject-Bridging-Header.h file and see whether it's missing the following line:

```
#import <ParseUI/ParseUI.h>
```

If so, be sure to add it.